# What does the scope operator(::) do when defining an inherited class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have found the following class definition to be confusing:

```
class Foo::Bar : public Example::Code
{
  // code
}
```

I’ve never seen an inherited class defined this way. Why is it defined with scope operators?
What exactly is it inheriting?

Comment: Which `::` are you confused by?

Comment: `Code` is either in a namespace named `Example` or defined inside another class or struct named `Example`. Same with `Foo::Bar`.

Comment: I would think that an example program in your C++ textbook that uses such syntax would also have an explanation of what this means, is there something in your textbook's explanation that's unclear?

Comment: Take comfort. The scope resolution here means the same thing as it does everywhere else.

Comment: This is unrelated to inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope resolution means the same thing everywhere: `Bar` is a name (of a class) in the scope named `Foo`, and `Code` is a name (of a class) in the scope named `Example`.

```
namespace Foo {
    class Bar;
}
namespace Example {
    class Code;
}
```

and then

```
class Foo::Bar : public Example::Code
{
  // code
};
```

Alternatively, the scopes might be classes, but fundamentally that's the same thing here.

```
struct Foo {
    class Bar;
}
struct Example {
    class Code;
}
```